# Python Attribute Error, not recocgnising object

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition

Im trying to make a small chatbot, using speech recognition but my code keeps bringing up an attribut error

My code is supposed to begin once run;

this is Chatbot;

```py
import numpy as np
import speech_recognition as sr

# Beginning of the AI
class ChatBot():
    def __init__(self, name):
        print("----- starting up", name, "-----")
        self.name = name
# Execute the AI
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ai = ChatBot(name="Dev")
#name of AI is codakai
# Execute the AI
```

A few lines later where the error apears

```py
# Execute the AI
if __name__ == "__main__":
     ai = ChatBot(name="Dev")
     while True:
         ai.speech_to_text()
```

The error during debugging;

```bash
PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\New folder> & C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe "c:/Users/User/Desktop/New folder/main.py"
----- starting up Dev -----
----- starting up Dev -----
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\New folder\main.py", line 34, in <module>
    ai.speech_to_text()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'ChatBot' object has no attribute 'speech_to_text'
```

Here is the entire code;

```
import numpy as np
import speech_recognition as sr

# Beginning of the AI
class ChatBot():
    def __init__(self, name):
        print("----- starting up", name, "-----")
        self.name = name
# Execute the AI
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ai = ChatBot(name="Dev")
#name of AI is Dev
# Execute the AI

#speech recognition with microphone, it converts it to text
def speech_to_text(self):
    recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as mic:
         print("listening...")
         audio = recognizer.listen(mic)
    try:
         self.text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
         print("me --> ", self.text)
    except:
         print("me -->  ERROR")

def wake_up(self, text):
    return True if self.name in text.lower() else False

# Execute the AI
if __name__ == "__main__":
     ai = ChatBot(name="Dev")
     while True:
         ai.speech_to_text()

def wake_up(self, text):
    return True if self.name in text.lower() else False

from gtts import gTTS
import os
@staticmethod
def text_to_speech(text):
    print("AI --> ", text)
    speaker = gTTS(text=text, lang="en", slow=False)
    speaker.save("res.mp3")
    os.system("start res.mp3")  # windows use->start
    os.remove("res.mp3")
```

Comment: Your `ChatBot` class doesn't have any `speech_to_text` method, as the error is pointing out. Did you mean to use something in the `sr` module?

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes i di, lemme try to use it real quick

Comment: @Carcigenicate I do not know how to use sr in the code, its been a while since ive coded on this file

Comment: What is `speech_to_text()` and why do you expect it to be part of `ChatBot()`?

Comment: @quamrana For recording, and to  be activated when ive said the ChatBots Name

Comment: The `speech_to_text()` function definition is **not** indented underneath the `ChatBot` class definition.

Comment: Your code doesn't really make sense. You create two `ChatBot()` instances and you have functions dotted about which look like they should be methods of a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Indentation seems incorrect,

> AttributeError: 'ChatBot' object has no attribute 'speech_to_text'

The error is generated because the class chatbot does not have a method speech_to_text therefore an error occurs when ai(object of chatbot) calls the method

Answer (score -1):

> The speech_to_text() function definition is not indented underneath
> the ChatBot class definition. –
> @John Gordon